# I am making an app and I put an iAd but I want it to hide when not available

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode, iad

I am making an application, that has iAd, but when I am not connected to the internet the space where the iAd is supposed to be, is a white empty space, how do I make it so the iAd space is not white, and is the same color as the background

If you could give me some code, that will be nice.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Add this in your .m file. This method checks if an Ad can be loaded. If it can't, it uses a nice animation to make the white space disappear. I'm also a noob to iOS programming, but this is how I did it in one app that I have in the App Store. I'm not sure if this is the best way but it works.

```
-(void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner
{
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
    [banner setAlpha:1];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}

-(void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
    [banner setAlpha:0];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Comment: it doesn't make the white space disappear.

Comment: I just edited my answer to show both methods. The first method displays the Ad if it is available. The second one makes it disappear if it is not available. I think you probably have to use these two methods together. That is probably why the it didn't work earlier.

Comment: Do i put this in the viewdidload

Comment: Don't put these in viewDidLoad. These go by themselves in the .m file. Don't put them inside of any other method. Are you using storyboards? My app uses storyboards and this works fine in my app. My app supports iOS 5.1 and later and it works perfectly. Sorry, I can't really say why your's is not working.

Comment: If it is not working and you need more help, why don't you post some more code :)

Answer (score 0):

Check this
 [iAd sample code](http://www.raywenderlich.com/1371/how-to-integrate-iad-into-your-iphone-app)

[iAd Example](https://github.com/WillChilcutt/iAd-Example)

[Shared iAd example](https://github.com/yarrd/Shared-iAd-example)